# How to resolve Profile matching query doesnot exist error in django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, runtime-error

I am new to Django framework. This problem "profile matching query does not exist" comes and I don't understand where this problem is generating from. Please Let me know what else code is needed to resolve this error. I will update this question.

profile matching query does not exist

!["profile matching query does not exist"]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfHio.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l6mF.png))

I have rechecked the code in urls.py, views.py, index file. But I could not resolve this.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('signup',views.signup, name = 'signup'),
    path('signin',views.signin, name = 'signin'),
    path('logout',views.logout, name = 'logout'),
    path('settings',views.settings, name = 'settings'),
    path('upload',views.upload, name = 'upload'),
]
```

views.py -> index

```
@login_required(login_url='signin')
def index(request):
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'user_profile':user_profile})
```

Comment: You're going to need to post some code from your `index` view. It's looking for a `Profile` that doesn't exist, and you're not handling the exception.

Comment: I have updated the question with views code.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so, it looks as though you don't have a `Profile` record associated with the `User` object.

```
def index(request):
    user_object = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
    user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)
```

You need to check the value of `user_object` before looking for the profile, though pretty sure this is OK, then handle that `Profile.objects.get` if it doesn't actually find an associated `Profile` record.

You could do this by

```
try:
   user_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user_object)
except Profile.DoesNotExist:
   ... handle the error here
```

Alternatively, you could use the `get_object_or_404` method, which would redirect you to your 404 page if it didn't find a record.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404